# How to make div fill remaining height of parent

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the `inner-main-dynamic-size` element (orange box) fill the remaining space of the `outer-fixed-size` element (red box/border)?

The element in question takes 100% of it's parents height, but since the parent has another child with a fixed size (the purple box), it gets pushed outside of the parent.

```css
.outer-fixed-size {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner-top-fixed-size {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
.inner-main-dynamic-size {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-fixed-size">
  <div class='inner-top-fixed-size'>
  </div>
  <div class='inner-main-dynamic-size'>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know I could harcode the `inner-main-dynamic-size` element to have `height: calc(100% - 50px)`, but I'd rather avoid having to hardcode these kind of calculations for something so simple, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your question correct and the two elements will always be on top of each other, then making the parent a flex-container (add `display: flex;`) could solve the issue. That way the child-divs will stay flexible.
`flex-direction: column` will ensure that the child-divs don't end up next to each other but stacked vertically.
`flex: 1` instead of height on the dynamic div will make it take up the remaining space.

More about [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) and a great [flex guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.outer-fixed-size {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inner-top-fixed-size {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
.inner-main-dynamic-size {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-fixed-size">
  <div class='inner-top-fixed-size'>
  </div>
  <div class='inner-main-dynamic-size'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @devklick Oops, sent my initial answer to quickly. Please note the added `flex: 1` on the dynamic child, so it can change size and not make the fixed-div shrink.

Answer (score 0):

That Magic happen by using **`flex`** layout.

```css
.outer-fixed-size {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.inner-top-fixed-size {
  /*height: 50px; instead flex basic*/ 
  flex-basis:50px;
  background-color: purple;
}
.inner-main-dynamic-size {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  flex:1;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-fixed-size">
  <div class='inner-top-fixed-size'>
  </div>
  <div class='inner-main-dynamic-size'>
  </div>
</div>
```